# Store relation into local file in pig not working

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I am new to pig and i am using a passwd file stored in /etc/passwd. I have started pig in local mode with following code

```
A = LOAD 'passwd' using PigStorage(':');
B = foreach A generate $0 as id;
STORE B INTO 'output';
```

Gives me the following error of job failed to produce result.The last line if written DUMP B;  generates output.Whats the problem here.?
Thanks in advance

```
Failed Jobs:
JobId   Alias   Feature Message Outputs
job_local_0004  A,B MAP_ONLY    Message: Job failed! Error - NA file:///home/monish/Desktop/output.txt,

Input(s):
Failed to read data from "file:///home/monish/Desktop/passwd"

Output(s):
Failed to produce result in "file:///home/monish/Desktop/output.txt"

Job DAG:
job_local_0004


2013-02-07 11:13:40,578 [main] INFO      org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.MapReduceLauncher - Failed!
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're invoking pig from your local directory (file:///home/monish/Desktop), and then using a relative path to load in the file.

Try and fully qualify the file path:

```
A = LOAD '/etc/passwd' using PigStorage(':');
```

Comment: Thank u @chris for the suggestion but the program is working fine when i edited the last line with 
    STORE B INTO '/tmp/output' 
dont know exactly wat was wrong but it worked with /tmp/output!!

Comment: Perhaps it might be an issue with the permissions?